# Android app navigation | custom navigation

Tags: java, android, dictionary, navigation, gesture

I think this could be a bit difficult.
I created an coordinate system, to build a game upon it. Since now your are able to move left and right by swiping. Is it possible to allow swipe up/down?
But I think its very annoying to swipe all the time, so I had the idea to add a system like google maps using it (move around by tap and hold).
Is there already a listener or something similar to include this, or does anybody know how to create something like that.
I've already searched around the web to find something... without success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: May you tell me whats wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an awnser myself, just use the OnTouchListener and catch the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and .ACTION_MOVE for example so you are able to always get the current touch position and calculate the difference between it and the start position and animate the map for this values.